# Magento2 - Change standard address format on Magento Frontend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, address, magento-2.1.2, format

I want to change Magento's standard address format to the one we use in the Netherlands.

For those who don't know the address format, it is the method in which we write the address. For example, the Dutch format is this:

```
Name
(Businesspark name etc.)
Street + number
Postal code + town
Country
```

The address format for the USA is this (Magento2 default):

```
Name of address
Street number and name
Name of town, State abbreviation + ZIP code
(typical handwritten format)
```

You can read more at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_%28geography%29).

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_address.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Login into **Magento Admin > STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration > Address Templates**

[image]

You also can find in the config xml: **vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml**

**[EDIT]**

We cannot use this config for billing and shipping format on checkout page. In this case, we need to check the format:

-`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

-`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html`

Comment: I see that you implemented this for Japanese store, and I would like to do the same. However, the change here is not working. Is it working for checkout page? I use magento 2.2.3

Comment: What's the page you want to change?

Comment: check out page, for billing and shipping address

Comment: For the checkout page, we cannot use this config. We need to override these html templates: `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html` and `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html`

Comment: Did you find a clean way to overwrite these two HTML template files?