# Magento 2 :Change order of billing address

Tags: magento2, billing-address, sort

In the customer account section,how can i edit the order of address data(billing and shipping)(ie, i want to show customer company first and customer name second)

https://prnt.sc/nucm3l

I found this in this template file

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/address.phtml
```

as

```
<?= $block->getPrimaryShippingAddressHtml() ?>
```

But this is coming as a single block.

From where i can edit this order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should try this guide https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/157954/33057

Comment: Thankyou..You saved my time:)

Comment: Leaving this link here when new users stumble upon: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html